On the volume of parallel rectangles contained in oblique rectangle
Consider the following lemma in these notes on measure theory (page 31 in the pdf):

Lemma 2.29. If an oblique rectangle $\tilde{R}$ contains a finite almost disjoint collection of parallel rectangles $\{R_1, R_2 \dots, R_N\}$ then
$$\sum_{i=1}^N v(R_i) \leq v(\tilde{R}).$$

The explanation that follows after the lemma:

This result is geometrically obvious, but a formal proof seems to require a fuller discussion of the volume function on elementary geometrical sets, which is included in the theory of valuations in convex geometry. We omit the details.

I wonder, what the author means by fuller discussion of the volume function. I would be very interested in seeing a proof of this lemma, since basically every theorem on rotational invariance of Lebesgue measure depends on this lemma. I've consulted A Concise Introduction to the Theory of Integration by Strooke and also Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space by Jones but have not been able to find a way to prove the above.
Below I've included definitions and some results that have already been proved in the text.

Some definitions; a parallel rectangle $R\subset \mathbb R^n$ is an $n$-fold Cartesian product of compact intervals, i.e. its sides are parallel to the coordinate axes. An oblique rectangle $\tilde{R}\subset\mathbb R^n$ is a rectangle whose sides are not parallel to the coordinate axes; it is obtained as the image under an orthogonal transformation $Q$ of a parallel rectangle, i.e. $Q(R)=\tilde{R}$. An almost disjoint collection of sets means that the sets intersect each other at most along their boundary. $v(\cdot)$ is the volume of a rectangle, i.e. the product of the length of its sides (where length of say $[a,b]$ is simply $b-a$). Note, that since an orthogonal transformation preserves lengths and angles, we have $v(\tilde{R})=v(R)$.

Some background material; the author notes prior to this lemma that $\mu(R)=v(R)$ for parallel rectangles $R$, where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure, but it has not yet been shown that $\mu(\tilde{R})=v(\tilde{R})$ for oblique rectangles $\tilde{R}$. Here are some proposition that have been proved earlier:

Proposition 2.6. If a rectangle $R$ is an almost disjoint, finite union of rectangles $\left\{R_{1}, R_{2}, \ldots, R_{N}\right\}$, then $$v(R)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} v\left(R_{i}\right).$$ If $R$ is covered by rectangles $\left\{R_{1}, R_{2}, \ldots, R_{N}\right\}$, which need not be disjoint, then $$v(R) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{N} v\left(R_{i}\right).$$


Proposition 2.11. Every rectangle is Lebesgue measurable. [The author remarks after this proposition that the interior of $R$, i.e. an open rectangle $R^{\circ}$ is measurable and its Lebesgue measure equals the Lebesgue measure of $R$. Moreover the boundary of $R$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.]


Proposition 2.20. Every open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a countable union of almost disjoint rectangles.


I think at least one way to approach would be along the lines of measure theory. If the rectangles $R_1,\dots,R_N$ contained in $\tilde R$ were pairwise disjoint, and $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure, then
$$
m(\bigcup_{j=1}^NR_j) = \sum_{j=1}^Nm(R_j).\tag{1}
$$
On the other hand, $\bigcup_{j=1}^NR_j\subset\tilde R$, so by monotonicity of Lebesgue measure,
$$
m(\bigcup_{j=1}^NR_j)\le m(\tilde R).\tag{M}
$$
Combining these two lines gives the claim in the case that the rectangles are pairwise disjoint.
The definition of "almost disjoint" rectangles is that rectangles only intersect along their boundaries. We have the following substitute for $(1)$ for any sets $R_1,\dots,R_N\subset\tilde R$:
$$
m(\bigcup_{j=1}^NR_j) \ge \sum_{j=1}^Nm(R_j) - \sum_{i<j}m(R_i\cap R_j).\tag{2}
$$
This formula is referred to as the inclusion-exclusion formula. Now we need a geometric fact about Lebesgue measure: if $E\subset\partial R$ is a measurable subset of the boundary of a rectangle, then $m(E) = 0$. Applying this fact, and our assumption that the rectangles are pairwise disjoint, we can upper bound
$$
\sum_{i<j}m(R_i\cap R_j)\le \sum_{i<j}m(\partial R_i) = \sum_{i<j}0 = 0.
$$
Plugging this bound into $(2)$, we get
$$
m(\bigcup_{j=1}^NR_j)\ge \sum_{j=1}^Nm(R_j)-0.\tag{3}
$$
By monotonicity $\text{(M)}$, we always have $m(\bigcup_{j=1}^N R_j)\le m(\tilde R)$. Combining monotonicity with $(3)$, we get
$$
\sum_{j=1}^Nm(R_j)\le m(\tilde R).
$$

The perspective of using Lebesgue measure may be overly complicated from the theory of valuations in convex geometry (something I am not familiar with), but it is natural and widely understood and taught for its generality and flexibility.

Thanks for the answer. Appreciate it. The text I'm studying makes a distinction between a volume function, which is basically only used on rectangles, and Lebesgue measure, defined on more general sets. Up to the lemma, it has been shown that the volume of a parallel rectangle equals the Lebesgue measure of that rectangle. However, it has not been shown that the volume of an oblique rectangle is equal to its Lebesgue measure. This is a later theorem that Lebesgue measure is invariant under isometries, and this theorem indirectly uses the lemma above. This is my dilemma :-)

One approach approach is to show that $\mu R = \mu \tilde{R} = \mu (QR)$. (The underlying result is the uniqueness of the Haar measure.)
Let $\nu A = \mu (QA)$ and note that $\nu$ is a translation invariant measure on the Borel sets.
Using translation invariance, it is straightforward to show that
$\nu [a_1,b_1]\times \cdots \times[a_n,b_n] = (b_1-a_1)\cdots(b_n-a_n) \nu[0,1]^n$ for all rational $a_k<b_k$, and a limit argument extends this to all real $a_k<b_k$. In other words, with $c= \nu[0,1]^n $, $\nu R = c \mu R$ for all rectangles $R$.
It is straightforward to check that $c \in (0,\infty)$.
Suppose $A$ is Borel and let $R_k$ be a covering by rectangles. Then
$\nu A \le \sum_k \nu R_k = c \sum_k \mu R_k$, and taking the $\inf$ on the right hand side shows $\nu A \le c\mu A$.
Since $A$ is measurable, we have $\nu R = \nu (R \cap A) + \nu (R \setminus A)$ and similarly for $\mu$. It follows from this that $\nu (A \cap R) = c\mu (A \cap R)$ for all rectangles and hence continuity of measure shows that $\nu A = c \mu A$.
To finish, we need to show that $c=1$. Note that we can write $Q = E_1 \cdots E_p$, where each $E_k$ is an elementary row operation. It is straightforward (using scaling or translation invariance on suitable partitions of a rectangle) to show that $\mu (E_k R) = |\det E_k| \mu R$ for all rectangles $R$. By considering the measure $A \mapsto \mu (E_kA)$ and applying the technique of the previous paragraph, we see that $\mu (E_k A) = |\det E_k|  \mu A$ for all $A$. Repeating, we get $\mu (QA) = |\det E_1| \cdots |\det E_p| \mu A = | \det Q| \mu A = \mu A$, the latter following from the fact that $Q$ is orthogonal.
